# .htaccess разброс по папкам

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, маршрутизация, angular5, http-redirect

Нужно настроить разброс по папкам через .htaccess

В корне проекта имеется 2 папки. Folder1 и Folder2.
Как можно реализовать что бы при посещении сайта все запросы шли в Folder1 и при этом в адресной строке вид ссылки был без http://domain/*
А при при запросе http://domain/blog/* бросало на папку Folder2  ?

Буду благодарен если мне так же бросят ссылку на норм доку где будет описано все символы которые можно использовать в htaccess что бы понимать что там и как.

Спасибо.

---

Пытаюсь реализовать так

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/$ blog/$1 [L]

Но не получается. Возможно потому что проект на ангуляре, и получается какой то ужас. И еще в папке2 тоже есть файл .htaccess с содержимым

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/index.html?path=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^/blog [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  /blog/$1  [L]
```